# Map XML attribute to specified tag(field) in Jackson Xml Mapper

Tags: java, xml, jackson, xml-attribute

I have a class:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public String a = "tag"

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    public String b = "attribute"

}
```

I need to set variable `b` as a property of variable `a`:

```
<SomeClass>
     <a b="attribute">tag</a>
</SomeClass>
```

I tried `@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)`, but it maps my attribute only to the root tag:

```
  <SomeClass b="attribute">
         <a>tag</a>
  </SomeClass>
```

It there a way to handle this problem with annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class A

```
public class A {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
  public String b = "attribute"
}
```

And use it in your class:

```
public class SomeClass {
  @JacksonXmlProperty
  public A a = "tag"

}
```